# Why does this cause a NullPointerException?

Tags: java, android

I have a program which is as follows, Can anyone tell me what is the reason for getting an NPE.

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        secondClass x = new secondClass();
        x.sText("Test Spring");

    }

}



public class secondClass extends MainActivity {

    public void sText(String s) {

        TextView text = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.text);
        text.setText(s);
    }

}
```

**Mainfest**

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    ...

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/hello_world"
        android:id="@+id/text"
     />

</RelativeLayout>
```

**LogCat**

```
08-16 01:31:11.320  15032-15032/? E/Trace: error opening trace file: No such file or directory (2)
08-16 01:31:11.420      836-987/? E/EmbeddedLogger: App crashed! Process: com.example.myapplication
08-16 01:31:11.420      836-987/? E/EmbeddedLogger: App crashed! Package: com.example.myapplication v1 (1.0)
08-16 01:31:11.420      836-987/? E/EmbeddedLogger: Application Label: My Application
08-16 01:31:11.420  15032-15032/? E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
        java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.myapplication/com.example.myapplication.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java)
        at de.robv.android.xposed.XposedBridge.main(XposedBridge.java:110)
        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
        Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
        at android.app.Activity.findViewById(Activity.java)
        at com.example.myapplication.secondClass.sText(secondClass.java:13)
        at com.example.myapplication.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:14)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java)
```

To my understanding, this should instantiate and initialize a secondClass object then call its sText() method. The sText method should then store a reference in TextView. Next it calls the setText() method on TextView, which changes the text in the TextView to what was passed into sText().

The logcat says it throws a NullPointerException but I'm not entirely sure why. If this is a rookie mistake, it's because I am a rookie. Thank you.

Comment: Why do you need `secondClass`?

Comment: Could you post your logcat, might help

Comment: Can you share more details what are you trying to archive. Having two activities instances is super rare case as well accessing one from another is not the way how android works

Comment: I want to have separate classes that handle different tasks within the app.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to Override `onCreate` in your secondActivity and have `setContentView(R.layout.mylayout)`. Then you can initialize your textview.

Also you need to start an Activity using intent

```
     Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivtiy.this,SecondActivity.class);
     startActivity(intent);
```

Remember to make an entry for the activity (SecondActivtiy) in manifest file

If you need to pass the string to second activity use intent.putExtra

```
      Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivtiy.this,SecondActivity.class);
      intent.putExtra("key",mystring); 
      startActivity(intent);
```

Then in secondActivity

```
    TextView tv ;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.mysecondlayout);
    tv = (TextView) findViewByid(R.id.textView1);
    Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
    if (extras != null) {
    String value = extras.getString("key");
    tv.setText(value);
    //get the value based on the key
    }
```

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#putExtra(java.lang.String, android.os.Bundle)

You can `findViewById` of the current view herarchy set to the activity.

Also you need to startActivity using intent rather doing this `econdClass x = new secondClass()`